# Is the set $E=\{0.a_1a_2... \in \mathbb{R}\mid a_i= 4 \text{ or } a_i=7\}$ dense, compact or perfect?

Tags: metric-spaces, proof-verification

I want to check my reasoning, I found that it's not dense but it's compact and perfect.

$1$- It's not dense for 1 is neither in the set of a limit point of it.

$2$- It's compact because it's both bounded ( clearly ) and closed. To show it's a closed set, I used the theorem which states that  if $A$ is a bounded above subset of $\mathbb{R}$ and $SupA \in A$ then $A$ is closed.

Here, it's clear that $SupE=0.7777777... \text{(all digits are 7's)}$ and clearly , this real number lies in $E$

So $E$ is both closed and bounded hence, compact

$3$-To show it's perfect, I show that every $x\in E$ is a limit point of $E$.

let  $x=0.x_1x_2x_3...$, 
and  $(a_1,a_2)$ be a neighborhood of $x$ where $a_2=0.h_1h_2....$

Assuming that $x\ne supE$,

Let $r$ be the smallest positive integer s.t. $x_i=h_i$ for $i\le r$.

If $h_r=4$ then $x_{r+1}\ge 5$ and if $h_r=7$ then $x_{r+1}\ge 8$. define $y=0.x_1x_2...x_{r}x_{r+1}Sx_{r+3}x_{r+4}...$ where $S=4$ if $x_{r+2}=7$ and $S=7$ otherwise.

It's clear that $x\ne y$ and $y\in E$ and $y\in (a_1,a_2)$ So   the neighborhood $(a_1,a_2)$ intersects $E$ in a point $y$ different than $x$ hence, x is a limit point of $E$

If $x=supE$ , we use the same process but this time we use $a_1$ instead of $a_2$.

So $E$ is perfect and we're done.

My question is, Is my reasoning right? are there any logical gaps? If no, Any better solutions?

Comment: It isn’t true that a set that is bounded above is closed if it contains its supremum: $(0,1]$ is bounded above and contains $1$, its supremum, but it’s not closed.

Comment: Dense in respect to what space?

Comment: Also, the two general ways to show closed are either A:  Show that the complement is open (I.e take a point not in the set and show a whole epsilon ball around that point is not in the set), or show the set contains all of its limit points (I.e. every limit point of the set is a member of the set itself)

Comment: @BrianM.Scott, You're right. I mis-read the theorem.

Comment: @Alan , in respect to the real number space.

Comment: Are you already familiar with the middle-thirds Cantor as the set of real numbers in $[0,1]$ that have ternary (base three) expansions using only $0$s and $2$s?

Comment: @BrianM.Scott, I've read its construction and some of its properites, I know what it's but I didn't use it in proving anything before (neither proved anything about it). Is it related to the situation here? ( I know ternary expansions of reals )

Comment: Yes, it is: if you take the numbers in your set, replace each $4$ by a $0$ and each $7$ by a $2$, and interpret the resulting strings as ternary expansions, you have a homeomorphism between your set and the middle-thirds Cantor set. Alternatively, you can construct yours by deleting middle intervals, though they won’t be thirds. For instance, starting with the interval $\left[\frac49,\frac79\right]$, you delete $(0.4\overline{7},0.7\overline{4})$ at the first step. The point is that your set has the same properties as the middle-thirds Cantor set.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott, hmm, I think I got the idea, we transformed $E$ into cantor's set which we know it's bounded and closed (hence compact) so we conclude that $E$ is compact too. This is awesome! . But I don't understand the definition of the term "homomorhism" here. I can see that $E$ has a structure (the metric) but What structure does cantor's set have?

Comment: *HomEomorphism*, not *homomorphism*; a homeomorphism is a map between topological spaces that preserves all of the topological structure (e.g., compactness). It’s the topological analogue of the algebraic notion of isomorphism, if you’re famliar with that: it’s a bijection that preserves topological structure. E.g., it takes open sets to open sets, closed sets to closed sets, convergent sequences to convergent sequences, non-convergent sequences to non-convergent sequences, etc.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott, Oh yes, I've studied homeomorphisms between topological spaces before. I was always reading them as "homomorphisms!" like in groups (I'm studying on my own so I don't compare words letter by letter). But I thnk that this needs - from me- some work, at least to show that this bijection is a homeomrphism, right? I also wonder if there is a "simpler" way to tackle this problem as cantor's set was not - I think -  mentioned in the text  - Rudin's analysis -  yet.

Comment: @MathsLover: You can show directly that the complement of $E$ is open: if the expansion of some real contains something other than $4$ or $7$, describe an open interval about that real that misses $E$. Of course $E$ is bounded, so once you know that it’s closed, you know that it’s compact. Finally, for any $x\in E$ it’s not hard to describe a sequence in $E$ converging to $x$, so $E$ has no isolated points.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott, Ok, Thank you for the help, Could you write an answer in order to close the question (instead of leaving it open). For your last comment about using sequences to prove that $E$ is perfect, it's a good idea. But I'm wondering, Isn't my proof that each $x\in E$ is a limit point of $E$ valid? "even if it's, your idea is more elegant"

Comment: @MathsLover: I will indeed write up an answer. I’ll have to take another look at your argument that $E$ is perfect: I got sidetracked with the other parts and didn’t really give it a close look.

Answer (score 0):

To show that $E$ is open, let $x\in\Bbb R\setminus E$, and show how to construct an open interval around $x$ that misses $E$. You can do this in terms of the decimal expansion of $x$. Say that the expansion is $0.d_1d_2\ldots\;$. Let $n\in\Bbb Z^+$ be minimal such that $d_n\notin\{4,7\}$. If $d_n=5$, say, let $a$ and $b$ have the expansions $0.d_1\ldots d_{n-1}4$ and $0.d_1\ldots d_{n-1}6$, respectively, and consider the interval $(a,b)$. I’ll leave it to you to figure out how to modify this idea when $d_n$ is $0$ or $9$.

Clearly $E$ is bounded, being a subset of $\left[\frac49,\frac79\right]$, so once you know that it’s closed, you know that it’s compact.

The idea behind your argument that every point of $E$ is a limit point of $E$ is fine, but there are some glitches in the argument as you’ve written it. First, I’m pretty sure that you meant to make $r$ the **largest** positive integer such that $x_i=h_i$ for all $i\le r$; then $r+1$ is the index of the first place in which the two expansions differ. (You actually assumed in your next paragraph that $r$ was the first place at which they differed, and in fact it’s a little easier to work with that, so I’d let $$r=\min\{i\in\Bbb Z^+:x_i\ne h_i\}\;.$$

At the next step you reversed the roles of $x_r$ and $h_r$. You want to say that if $x_r=4$, then $h_r\ge 5$, and if $x_r=7$, then $h_r\ge 8$. Now you can argue as follows. If there is an $s>r$ such that $x_s=4$, replace it with a $7$, let $x'$ be the resulting number, and show that $x'\in E\cap(x,a_2)$. Otherwise, $x_i=7$ for all $i>r$. In that case $x$ is not a limit point of $E$ from the right, and you should try to show (in very similar fashion) that $E\cap(a_1,x)\ne\varnothing$. Here you’ll find that you’re okay unless the expansion of $x$ ends in an infinite string of $4$s.

---

As I mentioned in the comments, this is really just a Cantor set. It can be constructed in the same fashion as the familiar [middle-thirds Cantor set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_set) $C$ by deleting middle open intervals, though they aren’t thirds. We start with the closed interval $\left[\frac49,\frac79\right]$. At the first step we remove $(0.4\overline{7},0.7\overline{4})$. At the next step we remove $(0.44\overline{7},0.47\overline{4})$ and $(0.74\overline{7},0.77\overline{4})$, and we continue in this fashion.

Alternatively one can show that if we map $E$ to $C$ by changing each $4$ and $7$ in the decimal expansion of $x\in E$ to $0$ and $2$, respectively, and interpret the resulting expression as the ternary expansion of a real number, the map is a homeomorphism.

Comment: I doubt that $E$ is even perfect. Consider $x=0.477777...$ and the neighborhood $Z=(0.476777... , 0.47877777)$, It's clear that $x\in Z$ and I think  that $Z$ doesn't contain any points of $E$ except $x$. What do you think?

Comment: @MathsLover: $Z$ contains $0.4774,0.47774,0.477774,\ldots$.